# I get a Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when running ionic app

Tags: php, angularjs, http, ionic-framework, wamp

I am using WAMP to to establish my pc as a server. I have some values in a database and now I want my ionic app to retrieve the data. In my app.js, I am using a get request to fetch whatever my php file gets from the db:

```
.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost//TempSensorTest/query.php")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
```

When I open this url in the browser, I get a json object with the values.

However, when i run the app on my android phone the console prints:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED   http://localhost//TempSensorTest/query.php
```

Note that around 3 months ago I used the same method for a different app and it did work. However I do not know what might be casung this now?

Comment: Does your app has access to `http://localhost`?

Comment: why would it not?

Comment: And what about the double `//` in the URL, between `localhost` and `TempSensorTest`?

Comment: Hello @AlonEitan, I did this edit but I still get the same error :(

Comment: I have exactly the same error. I hope someone could answer this.

Answer (score 2):

In second line you have "http:http://localhost//TempSensorTest/query.php"
try to remove first "http:".

Comment: Nice catch! They also have `//` in the path - Could be removed too

Comment: Oh thats a typing error here but originally it is only one http, still same problem.

Comment: Maybe you have to specify the port where the server is running, egx: "http://localhost:8080/TempSensorTest/query.php". if you don't specify the port, the default is simply 80.
if you put http://localhost/TempSensorTest/query.php on browser, do you get results?

Comment: yes I do get results, i am infact using port 80. @user2972221

Comment: @Sarahcartenz Any solution for this? I am also getting this error. I am using nodejs for my server.